# Let $f:(X,d) \to (Y,d’)$ and $A \subset X$. If $f(A)=\{y_0\}$. Show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=y_0$, when $x \in A$ and $x_0 \in \overline{A}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $f:(X,d) \to (Y,d’)$ and $A \subset X$. Also let $y_0 \in Y$ such that $f(A)=\{y_0\}$. Show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=y_0$, when $x \in A$ and $x_0 \in \overline{A}$.

I’ve tried to get an understanding of the problem and came up with the following sketch

[image]

All of $A$ maps to a single point in $Y$ and I want to show that the limit as $x$ approaches $x_0$ that’s in the closure of $A$ also maps to $y_0$. My understanding is that I want to show that since $x_0$ is in the closure of $A$ it’s also contained in $A$ and thus by the problem statement it should also map to $y_0$? So in essence is it the case that it would be enough to prove this if I show that $x_0 \in A$?

Comment: I think you map $f$ should be continuous, right?

Comment: What if $f$ is $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$ and $A=\Bbb P$, and $x_0=0$?

Answer (score 1):

If $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \notin \Bbb Q\\
                          1 & x \in \Bbb Q\\
\end{cases}$$

and $A= \Bbb Q$, then $f[A]=\{1\}$ but for any irrational like $x_0= \sqrt{2}$ we have that $x_0 \in \overline{A}$ but $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ does not exist. So you're missing an assumption.

Comment: Why $f$ is continuous ?